# The meaning of "Pause" in the following context

Tags: meaning-in-context, etymology, context

I have this phrase that I don't quite understand the meaning of in this context.

> Teile müssen vorsichtig entfernt werden. Wenn es während des Demontageprozesses zu einer **Pause** kommt, bringen Sie bitte Ihren eigenen Kleber zum Kleben und Reparieren mit.

So these are from the instructions for assembling a certain toy. I'm not a German speaker, so I don't know how to interpret this sentence. The usual meaning "pause" or "rest" doesn't really seem to fit the context. Could this word suggest that something breaks or something needs to be fixed? Dictionaries don't seem to agree with me though. What is the meaning of the word 'Pause' in this context?

Comment: It's probably a mistranslation of the English "break". It was translated as "Pause", but they probably meant "Bruch", "Riss", "Lücke". If your dictionary doesn't list these options, look out for a better one.

Comment: I agree with Arsak, that it is probably a poor translation, but would translate *Pause*  with *Unterbrechung* instead assuming this sequence of events: The glue hardens in the meantime and you need to bring a substitute by yourself.

Comment: The poor wording "bringen Sie bitte Ihren eigenen Kleber zum Kleben und Reparieren mit" also points to a bad translation.

Comment: Please add more context to the quote. I am a native German speaker and the phrase as it stands doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score -3):

#### Pause = interruption

The German word *»Pause«* is a loanword from Old French *»poser«* which has it's origin in the vulgar latin *»pausāre«* which means: to stop, to rest, to break. The origin of that vulgar latin word is the old greek word *»παῦσις«* (*paūsis*) which means: *end, stop, cease.*

The word *»pause«* is also part of the word *»menopause«* that exists in German and in English and literally means *»stop/end of month«* but means the last menstruation of a woman.

The atmosphere of our planet is divided in different layers which are called spheres (troposphere, stratosphere, mesosphere etc.) and the positions where these layers end are called tropopause, stratopause, mesopause etc.

But the meaning *»end«* got lost in the modern German word *»Pause«.* When you use this word in a German sentence, then you don't express an end, but an interruption. You expect that what ever was interrupted, will continue later, when the *Pause* ends.

*Pause* is the German word to name the free 5 to 15 minutes between the lessons in school, and it is also the word that you use when you have a short break during working, when you drink a cup of coffee or chat with colleagues. The break, in which you have lunch, is called *Mittagspause.* Also, when you speak, and stop speaking for a few seconds, then you make a *Sprechpause*. Before TV and radio stations were online 24/7, they had a *Sendepause* during night. Ski lifts in the mountains have a *Sommerpause* and open air baths have a *Winterpause.* In a battle, when both sides agree to interrupt firing on each other for some reason, this is a *»Feuerpause«.*

Also a rest in a music sheet is called *Pause* (music plays before the rest, then there is a short *Pause* = interruption, and then the music plays again).